Tableau Case statement not returning mutually exclusive values as specified
I've encountered an extremely perplexing problem in Tableau and hoping someone can help. I have a variable that contains 7 string values that correspond to numeric values in other columns in the data, of which I am only interested in four. Two of these values correspond to count values, and two correspond to rate values. I've created a parameter because I want users to be able to switch between these four measures on my dashboard. I'm using the following table calculation to build this visual:
CASE [Parameter 1]
WHEN "measure 1" THEN SUM([count 1])
WHEN "measure 2" THEN SUM([count 2])
WHEN "measure 3" THEN [rate 1]
WHEN "measure 4" THEN [rate 2]
ELSE NULL
END

The numeric values corresponding to the rate variables are already aggregated so they don't need the SUM operator. The "ELSE NULL" component is necessary to remove any numerical data for the 3 values of the string variable that I don't care about. This calculation successfully returns the mutually exclusive totals for the count measures, but it does not do so for the rate measures. The total for the rate measures is aggregated for all measures in the data and is not being treated as mutually exclusive.
Unfortunately I am unable to share the data due to sensitivity, but I'm hoping somebody can still help me figure out what's happening here.
Thank you.

Try fixing your rate values to the same level of detail as your counts eg. {FIXED [rate 1]}

The "ELSE NULL" is actually redundant. That's the default behavior

To help diagnose your problem, describe your input data more fully. Are the [rate 1] and [rate 2] calculated fields? or are they actual fields in your input data. What is their data type? If calculated, what is the formula? Same questions for your [court] fields

Nothing seems wrong with what you provided (just reproduced it in a test dashboard on Tableau desktop). That being said, one aspect that could cause the issue you are raising is the parameter entries not matching the entries in the case statement (double space, trailing characters, different name, etc.)
